# Why is state set to null immediately after setter function defined by useState is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I refactored my App.js into a functional component. When I try to login, my currentUser is set to a user, but then immediately set to null. I am confused why currentUser is set to null after it is given value. Is something calling `setCurrentUser` again to set it to null?

App.js:

```
const App = (props) => {
    const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState(null)
    const [ shoppingCart, setShoppingCart ] = useState([])

    const handleLogin = (email, password, history) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: { email, password},
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login'
        })
        .then( res => setCurrentUser(res.data.user))
    }
    console.log('this is currentUser', currentUser)

    return (
          <Switch>
            <div>
              <SideDrawer currentUser={currentUser} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser}/>
              <div className='App'>
                {/** OTHER ROUTES HERE **/}
                <Route path='/login' render={
                  () => {
                    return (
                      <Login handleLogin={handleLogin} history={props.history} currentUser={currentUser}/>
                    )
                  }
                    } />
                {/* Route to Signup page */}
                <Route path='/signup' render={
                  () => {
                    return(
                      <SignupForm setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} history={props.history}/>
                    )
                  }
                } />

              </div>
            </div>
          </Switch>
```

Login.js

```
const Login = ({history, handleLogin}) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [ values, setValues ] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        showPassword: false
    })

    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value})
    }

    const handleShowPassword = () => {
        setValues({...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword})
    }

    const handleMouseDownPassword = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (
        <Box className={classes.container}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <FormGroup>    
                <FormControl variant="outlined">
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.text}
                        variant='outlined'
                        multiline
                        name='email'
                        label="Email"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl variant='outlined'>
                    <TextField
                        label='Password'
                        className={classes.text}
                        type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        name='password'
                        margin="normal"
                        variant='outlined'
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        InputProps={{
                            endAdornment: (
                                <InputAdornment>
                                    <IconButton
                                        onClick={handleShowPassword}
                                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                    >
                                    {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                                    </IconButton>
                                </InputAdornment>
                            )
                        }}
                    />
                </FormControl>
                <Button 
                    variant='contained'
                    className={classes.button}
                    onClick={ () => handleLogin(values.email, values.password, history)}
                >
                    Login
                </Button>
            </FormGroup>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you determining `currentUser` is being set null? Please include debugging details and reproducible steps when asking for help with an issue/bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is setting it to null.

Either:
`.then( res => setCurrentUser(res.data.user))`

or `SideDrawer` or `SignupForm` are calling `setCurrentUser(null)`.

If you remove both `SideDrawer` and `SignupForm` you can check the functionality of the `.then( res => setCurrentUser(res.data.user))` line.

Then add back `SideDrawer` and see if that is causing it to be set to null. Lastly, add back `SignupForm` and see if that's the culprit.

Comment: You were right! In `SideDrawer`, I never set my logout function to a callback. So it automatically logged out my user and made it null! Thank you!